# How to authenticate an insert or return error

Tags: django

im implementing a simple API CRUD using Django + Django rest and have a doubt.
I have two models:

```
class Shoe(models.Model):
    _id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)
    provider = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=TIPO_CHOICES, null=False, blank=False)
    cost_price = models.DecimalField(
            max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, verbose_name = 'Preço de Custo',
            null=False, blank=False
            )
    sale_price = models.DecimalField(
            max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, verbose_name = 'Preço de Venda',
            null=False, blank=False
            ) 

class Stock(models.Model):
    _id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    id_shoe = models.ForeignKey(
            Shoe, on_delete = models.CASCADE, verbose_name = 'shoe', related_name = 'stock')
    size = models.IntegerField(choices=NUMERACAO_CHOICES, null=False, blank=False)
    amount = models.IntegerField(null=False, default=0)
```

What I am wanting is, when someone tries to make an insertion of stock of a size (of a certain shoe) that already exists it returns error. I can not just be 'unique' in the parameters of size. Any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want only one `Stock` item for each unique combination of `shoe` and `size`, you can use [**`unique_together`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#unique-together) here:

```
class Stock(models.Model):
    shoe = models.ForeignKey(Shoe, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='shoe', related_name='stock')
    size = models.IntegerField(choices=NUMERACAO_CHOICES, null=False, blank=False)
    amount = models.IntegerField(null=False, default=0)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('shoe', 'size')
```

> **Note** the name of a `ForeignKey` is usually *not* prefixed or suffixed with `id_` or `_id`, Django automatically creates a "twin" field with the `_id` suffix that stores the primary key of the referenced value.

> **Note**: If you do not specify a primary key, Django will automatically make one named `id`, so here it is probably better to let Django implement the logic.

Comment: Thank you, I didnt know any Meta parameters besides `verbose_name`,  `verbose_name_plural` and `ordering`. Thats awesome!

Comment: @TâmerPinheiro: the link of `unique_together` shows the documentation page that lists all sorts of extra options.

Comment: This `_id` is for the pk column on my database mantain a stardard that I need in this project. I know that is better just let Django take care of it.

Comment: @TâmerPinheiro: sure, you can keep it. That is not a problem for `unique_together`. The notes are just "common practice", but not necessary such that it works properly.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using Django 2.2 you can use `UniqueConstraint` instead of `unique_together` like this:

```
class Meta:
    constraints = [
        models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['shoe', 'size'], name='give_it_some_name')
    ]
```

As the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/options/#unique-together) state:

> Use UniqueConstraint with the constraints option instead.
>
> UniqueConstraint provides more functionality than unique_together. unique_together may be deprecated in the future.